# Sanitizing User Input

Tags: sql, r, sql-injection

I'm writing an R application in which I'm interacting with a SQL database using the `RODBC` package. I'm looking up items in the database based on columns in a .csv file. Although I have no reason to expect malicious content in these files, I'd much rather be safe than sorry.

How do you sanitize user input for use in a SQL query in R? In most languages I've come across, there were libraries that would accept a string, and return a sanitized string back to you. Does anything like that exist in R?

Answer (score -1):

You could always use [regular expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) to construct an accepted pattern and remove the cases that don't match.
I'd try that to be in full control. Don't know of any ready made checks.